# \cite{*} does not always work

Tags: citing

I've tried to use `\cite{*}` in my main .tex file (which is full of writing). It didn't add in the uncited refs. It just included those refs called elsewhere by `\cite{x}`. The I deleted all contents between `\begin{document}...\end{document}` (except the bibliography commands and `\cite{*}`), then it works. So there is something in the main body of my document that is preventing `\cite{*}` from working.

In the long run I'm wishing to use `refcheck` to see what I haven't yet cited.

Has anybody seen this behaviour before? Sorry I haven't included a MWE as there are quite a few packages.
thanks

Comment: I believe you're looking for `\nocite{*}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\nocite{*}` to include all entries in the *.bib* file and `\nocite{<key>}` to include specific entries.

Comment: ack. thanks. egg on face. Sometimes working by memory doesn't always work out well.